# Ask questions side by side

Tags: pdftex, alignment

[image: Exemple]

How do I put questions side by side?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? Could you post a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for us to work with?

Comment: Have a look at the `multicol` package.

Comment: Could you also clarify your question. What to you have, what do you ... ?

Comment: As Alain mentions `multicol` and a normal list will be able to produce this. You manu need to add `\displaystyle` to each piece of math.

Comment: use the `tasks` package!